# Is it possible to shorten $mysqli->queries?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What I mean is, when MySQL was supported you could do things like this (sorry if this code is wrong, just making this question very quickly):

```
<?php
 $user = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Accounts` WHERE `ID`='$userID'"));
?>
```

Is this in any way possible with mysqli? I think it's not, but I just wanted to make sure. I've tried and it hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. You should do:

```
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT 'A world full of ' AS _msg FROM DUAL");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
echo $row['_msg'];
```

Comment: Yep, thought so. After my test, this worked. Thanks for making sure.